# Ruby: How to sum/count table entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a join table (favorites) that combines users with menu_items (another join table consisting of dishes and restaurants).

I want to create a table that lists out the most popular dishes (dishes that occur most often in the table), and the top restaurant for each dish. I'm most of the way there, but not sure how to do the count. Any tips?
[Most Popular Dishes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SdJZ.png)

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <tr>
    <!-- <th>Dish comment</th> -->
    <th>Dish</th>
    <th>Restaurant</th>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>

  <% @favorites.each do |favorite| %>
  <tr>
    <!-- <td><%= favorite.dish_comment %></td> -->
    <td><%= Dish.find(favorite.dishing_id).dish_name %></td>
    <% d = Dishing.find(favorite.dishing_id) %>
    <td><%= Restaurant.find(d.restaurant_id).name %></td>
    <td><%= User.find(favorite.user_id).email %></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try group, count after join.

```
User.joins(menu_items)
          .select(count(menu_items.id) as dish_count, menu_items.dish_name, users.name)
          .where(<conditions>)
          .group(menu_items.dish_name)
```

Comment: Thanks! Where does this go in my code? Under here?   <% @favorites.each do |favorite| %>

Comment: Please try in your controller